# Can you identify this crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, identification

I've always used the internal oscillator in my AVR microcontroller projects, but have discovered that I need to use an external oscillator to increase the clock frequency. I have some of these 20MHz crystals in the spare parts bin, but I can't find a datasheet.

Searches for "MPC" and "970T" aren't providing any useful hits. I'm brand new to using crystals, and as such I am going to have a bit of work ahead to learn the ropes. Before I can get started I'd like to at least try using the ones I have on hand.

Do you recognize the logo or markings on this part, and if so can you point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

This is a 4-pin device which is why I believe it is a crystal oscillator rather than just a crystal.

[image: 20MHz crystal oscillator]

Comment: @PeterJ Yes it does. I'm discovering this is a crystal oscillator as opposed to a standard crystal with 2 pins. (Which explains its size compared to smaller ones I've seen.)

Comment: Some useful information on crystals for AVR uses: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=1027265

Comment: I thought XOs all had the same pinout (Vcc at 14, GND at 7, Out at 8).

Comment: Sorry I'd removed my comment about it being an oscillator module, I had a facepalm moment and read the title as crystal

Comment: @PeterJ It's ok, you prompted me to include the note about it having 4 pins.

Comment: MPC - Monitor Products Company, Inc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it. MPC is Monitor Products Company, bought out by [MMD Components (MMD Monitor/Quartztek Frequency Control Products)](http://mmdcomp.com/) in 2002.

[970T Datasheet Low-Cost, Full-Size TTL-compatible Clock Oscillator](http://pccomponents.com/datasheets/mpc-970t.pdf)

Comment: You'll have to share your Google-Fu secrets, I couldn't find this (and I am generally pretty decent finding things!).

Comment: @Jyelton googled 'M PC Crystals', found an ebay auction with a similar product, and datasheet. Lead me to Monitor Products Company, who's website is gone. So I searched for their name and city, which lead me to a company profile mentioning MMD Components. Knowing companies get swallowed all the time, once I searched that, the Monitor name was in MMD's name (Like Maxim-Dallas did to Dallas). Also, for the datasheet, all I had to find was Monitor Products Company 970T. First hit.

Comment: I see; I saw the ebay links but didn't think to go there. Perhaps because I've encountered a fair number of things there with no useful links. Much thanks for your help.